# Adding a Facebook app administrator who is not a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, roles, accounts

Having searched through this section many times, I am struggling to find an answer to what I thought would be simple:

Having created an app, I cannot add other facebook verified developer accounts as administrators of the app without first friending them.

This is a professional app (we are using it to provide login through Facebook services), and I cannot find a way to add other colleagues without making them into facebook friends.

I have tried:

> Roles > Administrators > Add:

- Email address
- UID
- Link to Profile URI
- Name search

I either get back nothing, or a notice that the user is not a facebook user (though they patently are, I can add them as a friend after all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check with the user to see if they got the notification? (e.g. you should receive a request from me)

This is how a pending request looks.

[image: Pending Request]

Comment: Hi phwd,

I got the notification indeed. However, when I add people, it will just tell me they're not users (unless I friend them). I've just added you to the app, for an example, and it won't flag anything at all.

Comment: ![Screengrab](http://zachbeauvais.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Screen-Shot-2012-11-29-at-10.27.02.png)

Comment: @ZachBeauvais are you adding with the id? If so you should just file a bug. The option to add non-friends is allowed

Answer (score 2):

1) You must acess the apps via: https://developers.facebook.com/apps and select your app. The UI has recently been updated:

[image]

2) If the user is not your friend you must add them using facebook User Id otherwise it will not work.

This can be obtained via http://findmyfacebookid.com/ which wil turn thier profile url into an id.

3) The user must also have [verified](https://www.facebook.com/help/verify) their account. However it will tell you this when you try to add them.

4) They will then receive a request which they must accept.